# Javascript regext not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have website with content some thing like below.I want to get **activategoldodgbrm**

```
App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">activategoldodgbrm</div>
```

I tried below code , but it says match is not working.

```
var pattern = /App Namespace<\/span><\/div><div class="fsm fcb">(.*?)<\/div>/gm;
var match;
while (match = pattern.exec(src)) { 

alert(match[1]);

}
```

Note: src contains my page source

Comment: No line feeds in your src?

Comment: Would it not be better to use DOM selectors to find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're simply misunderstanding the `m` modifier. It does give you the opportunity the match something over several lines BUT you have to deal with the new lines (`\r\n` or `\n`).

Consider this example:

```
"</span>\n</div>".match(/.*/m);
```

This will only give you "". Because we forgot to consider the new lines here. This would catch all:

```
"</span>\n</div>".match(/(.|\r?\n)*/m);
```

So... as we don't really know what's in `src`, I'll try to be more generic:

```
var pattern = /App Namespace(?:\r?\n)*<\/span>(?:\r?\n)*<\/div>(?:\r?\n)*<div class="fsm fcb">(?:\r?\n)*(.*?)(?:\r?\n)*<\/div>/gm;
```

(included lots of new lines catching)

As a side-note, the dot `.` doesn't catch new lines characters.

Comment: src is the page source, that contains App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">activategoldodgbrm</div> , your pattern did not work.

Comment: Well I'll ask for a jsfiddle. Cause we probably can't fix the problem when we don't have enough data.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't assigned anything to match.

```
var a;
if(a==1){...}
alert(a); // a is null
```

so try this

```
var pattern = /App Namespace<\/span><\/div><div class="fsm fcb">(.*?)<\/div>/gm;
var match;
while (match = pattern.exec(src)) { // using "=" instead of "=="

alert(match[1]);

}
```

Comment: And he did this according to previous answer by @user125697

Comment: this worked `<div><span>
adfasdgadg
asdfasdg

asdf
App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">abd</div>
<div><span>App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">1212</div>

<script>
var pattern = /App Namespace<\/span><\/div><div class="fsm fcb">(.*?)<\/div>/gm;
var match;
while (match = pattern.exec(document.body.innerHTML)) { 

alert(match[1]);

}</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Please abstract from answers about == and = operators, it was some misunderstanding. First, I don't think you need such complex regex. Second, you don't need run the cycle. Check this:

```
var src = 'App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">activategoldodgbrm</div>';
alert(/class="fsm fcb">(.+?)</gm.exec(src)[1]);
```

Finally, if your src is actually DOM nodes it's better to use DOM API to find node and get innerHTML of it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhmpw/)

Comment: You simply took the most specific example for your src. This won't work in most of the cases I guess.

Comment: not working , in website, there is one or more <div class="fsm fcb"> , so i need regex for whole App Namespace</span></div><div class="fsm fcb">

Comment: So it's not a string, but DOM nodes tree. You definetely should use nodes traversing then.